# Splitting train_test.prototxt into train.prototxt and test.prototxt

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

In Caffe, when configuring a neural neutral architecture, one can either define one single train_test.prototxt, or 2 prototxt files train.prototxt and test.prototxt.

For instance, in the examples, [hdf5_classification](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/hdf5_classification) uses 2 prototxt files ([nonlinear_auto_train.prototxt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/hdf5_classification/nonlinear_auto_train.prototxt) and [nonlinear_auto_test.prototxt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/hdf5_classification/nonlinear_auto_test.prototxt)), while [mnist](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/mnist) uses 1 prototxt file ([lenet_train_test.prototxt](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt)).

What difference does that make to use 2 prototxt files instead of 1?

Comment: @runDOSrun thank you, I am aware of the difference between training and test sets. How does that help answering the question?

Comment: Since this has gone unanswered, I'll have a quick stab. I have found that, in Matlab, the random segregation of train/test/validation datasets from the parent data has a profound impact on the ability of the resulting network to converge. Perhaps the ability to explicitly specify the data segmentation is to help you with k-fold cross-validation i.e. the segmentation is repeatable?

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks. In Caffe, even if you use 1 prototxt file containing train and test you can still explicitly specify the data segmentation.

Comment: Ah, that leaves me at a loss then. Other than it being the preference of the Author to keep them separate, the only other thing I can think of is that the explicitly defined test set is for some sort of completely external test, simply to illustrate how the validated network can be applied elsewhere. But I really don't know, so hopefully someone will clarify for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Merging train and val .prototxt files into a single file is an attempt at reducing the number of files required to drive an experiment. See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/LpXNE42hfG0) post in the caffe-users group regarding the general intent to merging files.
I don't know if the plan is to have single file solutions and eliminate any splitting, but can imagine it be kept for advanced purposes, where the user wishes to have vary test conditions while keeping training conditions constant.